# How to add new forms in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have to add some forms for various purpose like getting info from client regarding a product, getting query from customers, some lead forms.

So how can i add new forms in magento other than having new module for forms. The form will be working with some custom db tables or need to mail them to admin/customer.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Magento is built on MVC model, i think u should add module in order to use any form.

And if you are reluctant in using them, then there is a possibility of having plain php pages outside magento folder and add those links inside magento either using static blocks or CMS Pages..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i have added just form with mailing option. Now can i have multiple forms with in same module.